# overloading or overriding equals() method

Tags: java, oop, overriding

I'm a little confused as to what gets called first in the following scenario:

I've got a Person class with a name and an age.

```
public class Person {
  private int age;
  private String name;

  //constructor, getters, ...
}
```

I now try to compare two separate `Person` objects with the same field values i.e. same name, same age

```
System.out.println(person1.equals(person2));
```

I obviously receive a `false` return value because I haven't overriden the `equals(Obj object)` method yet.

But say I don't override it, I instead write another `equals()` method only with a `Person` argument:

```
public equals(Person person) {
  return person.get_age()==this.age && person.get_name().equals(this.name);
}
```

Which method gets called now and why? The line below still returns `false`

```
System.out.println(person1.equals(person2));
```

unless I force `person2` to be interpreted as a `Person`. The line below therefore returns `true`

```
System.out.println(person1.equals((Person)person2));
```

Here's what's confusing me, I now remove that type cast to `Person` and for some reason, when I build and run the code again and again, it keeps coming back `true`. The only way to force it to start returning `false` again, i.e. to keep taking the default `equals(Object obj)` method again is by deleting the `equals(Person person)` method, running the code once, and then pasting back the method I had just deleted. Now the comparison keeps returning `false` again.

Is some inbetween state being cached by the JVM? I'm a little new to java in all honesty.

Comment: You keep saying "overload" when you mean "override". If you write a new `equals(Object)` method, that is *overriding*. If you write an `equals` with any other argument, that is *overloading*.

Comment: Watch your upper/lowercase typing. I fixed `Public` & `person` to `public` & `Person` for you.

Comment: Assuming `person2`is declared to be a `Person`, then the cast `(Person)person2` has nil effect.

Comment: By the way, here is some simpler code to practice: https://ideone.com/tujF0k

Comment: thanks for fixing my upper/lowercase typing @BasilBourque

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Overriding* is when you implement a method that has been declared in a superclass.  To qualify as an override, the signature of the override must match (within some tolerance) the signature of the method being overridden.  ​

*Overloading* is when you have multiple methods with the same name but different signatures.

In the presence of overloads, which one is called is determined solely by the *static types of the arguments at the call site*.  In your example, you have two overloads of `equals`:

```
boolean equals(Object o) { ... }
boolean equals(Person p) { ... }
```

When you call:

```
Person p = ...
... equals(p) ...
```

the overload selection process proceeds as follows:

- Determine the static types of the arguments.
- Determine which overloads are applicable (using arity, subtyping, conversion, etc.)
- If more than one is applicable, determine the most specific one.
- If two or more are equally specific, a compile-time error is issued.

Here, the argument type is `Person`, and both overloads are applicable (since a `Person` is an `Object`), but `equals(Person)` is more specific, so that one is called.

If we changed the story slightly:

```
Object p = new Person(...);
... equals(p) ...
```

Now, the static type of `p` is `Object`, so only the first overload -- `equals(Object)` -- is applicable.  All we know is that it is an `Object`; that it happens to hold a `Person` is something that we don't know statically.  (We could find it out dynamically with `instanceof`.)

To summarize:

- Expressions have both a static (compile-time) and dynamic (run-time) type;
- Overload selection is done purely on the basis of static types.

Now, you probably don't want to declare `equals(Person)` for the same problems you're seeing here -- it looks like an override, but really its an overload, and won't get called when you think it does.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain the issue, Brian. I'll avoid doing this in the future

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Person` has two methods:

- `boolean equals(Person);`
- `boolean equals(Object);` (from Object)

So obviously `person2` is not recognized as `Person`.
The likely explanation is forgotten (dropped) generic typing.

```
Person person = new Person();
List<Person> list = new ArrayList(); // Should have been new ArrayList<>();
...
if (person.equals(list.get(0)) { // equals(Object)
```

With pre-generic typing the compiler no longer checks and falls back on a List of Objects. Maybe your IDE gives a corresponding warning (orange marker).

---

Tip:

- Use `getAge` and `getName`; camel case in Java. Conventions in java are kept quite strict everywhere.
- Do not overload `equals` and use `@Override`. So much depends on the original `equals`, and IDEs are known to warn on `personJoop.equals(dog)` that it will always fail.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Joop; those C++ naming habits are hard to break. And I'll stick to using `@Override` in the future.
My IDE (IntelliJ) has indeed suggested I use `Objects.equals()` instead in order to avoid the confusion